# Predict function in R output Exact useful part

Tags: r, list

Having trouble extracting the useful part of the output of a prediction function in R.
The output is a list. How could I only obtain the predict response part?

Example below:

```
x=c(1,0,2,0,3,1,0,1,2,0)
y=c(16,9,17,12,22,13,8,15,19,11)
fit=lm(y~x)
prit=predict(fit,data.frame(x=x))
prit
```

Output:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
14.2 10.2 18.2 10.2 22.2 14.2 10.2 14.2 18.2 10.2
```

I forgot to mention, I would like to have only
14.2 10.2 18.2 10.2 22.2 14.2 10.2 14.2 18.2 10.2

I thought this would work but

```
prit[[c(1:10)]]
Error in prit[[c(1:10)]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: The output is not a list but a named vector. You can see it by doing `str(prit)` or `is.vector(prit)`.

Comment: you're using `[[]]` which as the error states allows for the retrieval of one element, use `prit[1:10]` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error rises from the use of the `[[` function instead of `[`:

- `[` == `[]`  always returns object of same class as the parent object, allows for multiple element selection.
- `[[` == `[[]]` = can extract only one element, returned object is not necessarily of the same class i.e it returns exactly the element found at the index that was provided.

```r
> l <- list(x=1, y=2, l=list(z=1))
> l[1]
$x
[1] 1
> str(l[1])
List of 1
 $ x: num 1
> l[[1]]
[1] 1
> str(l[[1]])
 num 1
```

So you're using `[[` to extract multiple elements which leads to the error stated in your question.

Also use `1:10` directly no need to use `c(1:10)`

```r
> prit[1:3]
   1    2    3 
14.2 10.2 18.2 
> unname(prit)
14.2 10.2 18.2 10.2 22.2 14.2 10.2 14.2 18.2 10.2
```

Comment: str(prit)
 Named num [1:10] 14.2 10.2 18.2 10.2 22.2 14.2 10.2 14.2 18.2 10.2
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...

Comment: that means that it's a named vector however that doesn't chang the validity of the question.